# ggplot from two tibbles; scatterplot with contours in background

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two tibbles -

1. tbl1 contains real data : X, Y and choice.
2. tbl2 is synthetic tibble to calculate contours of predicted choice P.

```
library(tidyverse)

# tibble1
X <- c(1, 3, 5) 
Y <- c(1, 5, 3) 
choice <- c(0, 1, 1) 
tbl1 <- tibble(X,Y,choice)

# tibble2
X <- seq(0, 5, 0.1) 
Y <- seq(0, 5, 0.1) 
tbl2 <- crossing(X,Y)
tbl2 <- tbl2 %>%
mutate(V = (X + Y - 4)/2, 
       P = 1/(1+exp(-V)))
```

I wish to create a single ggplot with

1. scatterplot X vs Y from tbl1 (with color = choice)
2. filled contours of P from tbl2 in the background

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(tbl2, aes(X, Y)) + 
  geom_contour_filled(aes(z = P), alpha = 0.3) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(choice)), size = 5, data = tbl1) + 
  guides(fill = guide_none()) + 
  labs(color = "Choice")
```

[image]